# <hx:inputHelperDatePicker/> UI corrupted

Tags: datepicker, websphere

I'm using IBM http://www.ibm.com/jsf/html_extended custom components in two different pages, one of them displays date picker in a stylish way like the left photo [photo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAgAj.jpg) and it's code

```html
<tr>

  <td width="20%">To Date:
    <FONT id="toDtColor" color="red" style="display:inline">*</FONT>
  </td>
  <td width="30%">
    <h:inputText id="textSearchToDate1" value="#{SearchTransactionView.searchToDate}" styleClass="mediumInput" disabled="false" readonly="false">
      <hx:convertDateTime timeZone="#{BaseBean.defaultTimeZone}" pattern="EEE, dd MMM yyyy" />
      <hx:inputHelperDatePicker id="datePicker1" />
      <hx:inputHelperAssist errorClass="inputText_Error" id="assist1" />
    </h:inputText><br/>
    <h:message for="textSearchToDate1" styleClass="fieldError"></h:message>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Then I used this code again in another page,but I found the result like the right photo in photo1 link above.
and the code is

```html
<tr>
  <td width="20%" valign="top">User Expiration Date:</td>
  <td width="30%">
    <h:inputText id="UserExpirationDate" value="#{AddUserView.userExpiryDate}" styleClass="mediumInput">
      <hx:convertDateTime timeZone="#{BaseBean.defaultTimeZone}" pattern="EEE, dd MMM yyyy" />
      <hx:inputHelperDatePicker id="datePicker100" />
    </h:inputText>
    <br/>
    <h:message for="UserExpirationDate" styleClass="fieldError"></h:message>
  </td>
</tr>
```

So what is the problem of using this component?

Answer (score 0):

The second code fails to specify a font explicitly unlike the first snippet which appears to be causing the font in the second photo to be improperly sized.

Comment: This font element is for adding (  *  ) beside the title of this field , so it doesn't impact the datepicker component.

Comment: The mistake was missing importing css file in this page.